# How do you directly load a value from Object additionalViewData in Html.Editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In Html.Editor (technically [EditorExtensions.Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406519.aspx)) there is an overload with the signature of

```
public static MvcHtmlString Editor(
    this HtmlHelper html,
    string expression,
    Object additionalViewData
)
```

How exactly are you supposed to use additionalViewData? The MSDN documentation is not clear at all.

My first thoughts were along the lines of:

`@Html.Editor("quijibo", new { quijibo = "homer simpson" })`

However this doesn't work so I'm at a loss at this point.

**Edit:** Revised question to be How do you directly load a value from Object additionalViewData in Html.Editor? I want a value I place in additionalViewData to be used as the data value of that editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is that it is impossible with the built in classes.

The code structure of them overwrites anything you would stuff into

`htmlAttributes: new { value = "x" }`.

I found this to be very inconvenient. I created methods to parallel the internal workings of the MVC methods that are all similar to:

```
private static TagBuilder CreateHiddenTag(string inputName, object value, 
        object htmlAttributes)
{
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");

    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", inputName);

    tagBuilder.GenerateId(inputName);

    if (value != null)
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", value.ToString());

    if (htmlAttributes != null)
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), 
            replaceExisting: true);

    return tagBuilder;
}
```

The major difference is that I ordered calls such that `tagBuilder.MergeAttributes` is **last** so that you can always override ANYTHING using the `object htmlAttributes`. The MVC source code goes the opposite way and applies the attributes first, thereby making their solution substantially less flexible.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Html.Editor("quijibo", new { quijibo = "homer simpson" })
```

and inside the corresponding editor template you could fetch the value from ViewData:

```
@ViewData["quijibo"]
```

or ViewBag if you prefer:

```
@ViewBag.quijibo
```

Full example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Name = "abc"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.Editor("Name", new { foo = "bar" })
```

and inside the editor template that's being called (`~/Views/Shared/string.cshtml`):

```
@model string
<span>@Model</span>
<span>@ViewData["foo"]</span>
```

Personally I would recommend you using the strongly typed helper `Html.EditorFor` taking a lambda expression instead of `Html.Editor`.

Comment: I want the value of `quijibo =` to be the value of the editor, is that not possible without creating a custom editor template? That's my entire purpose is to avoid needing custom editor templates.

Comment: Using EditorFor isn't an option, that's what I'm trying to build, an EditorFor that doesn't suck when it comes to dynamic client side lists. And as you showed you needed a custom editor for string, I'm trying to build a html helper that doesn't require absurd amounts of knowledge of the internal workings of it, and pieces of stuff every where to make it work.

Comment: Be default, the view bag given to your editor is the same as the view data for the view invoking the editor. You could try creating an editor for Object, and performing your view data checking logic inside of that editor, and redirecting to the appropriate editor. However, Object is the last editor to be checked for a match, thus any other editor that matches better would be used instead. This includes the default editor.

Comment: I would start checking what Html.EditorFor is doing, and try to imitate that, but with your own customizations. It is an extension method, after all. It shouldn't be too terribly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own HtmlHelper. Create your own file HtmlHelper.cs and have fun. Following example to display the anonymous objects:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayObject(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, object anonymousModel)
        {
            string result = anonymousModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(anonymousModel).ToString();

            return new MvcHtmlString(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is your View:

```
@Html.DisplayObject("quijibo", new { quijibo = "homer simpson" })
```

Ask google about "mvc custom html helper" if you want more information. Good luck.